# Deep clone a MongoDb document with embedded documents ID's (tree structure)

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am struggling on finding a solution based on deep cloning a given document which has embedded documents ID's, but those embedded documents might also have other embedded documents ID's. I want to create copies of these embedded documents in the specific collections they belong to and build up the parent(root) document that has references to these newly added documents. So for example I have this schema:

**1. page**

```
{ 
"_id" : 123456789, 
"page_title" : "Title 1",
"sections" : [111, 222, ...]
"variables" : [v1, v2, ...]
}
```

**2. sections**

```
{ 
"_id" : 111, 
"section_tag" : "Section 1",
"sections" : [333, ...]
"blocks" : [1212, 2323, ...]
}
```

**3. blocks**

```
{ 
"_id" : 1212, 
"block_type" : "paragraph" (or image etc.),
"content" : "<p> content goes here...</p>"
"conditions" : [condition_id_1, condition_id_2, ...] (these are also embedded documents)
}
```

So first of all I have to clone the document named 'page' and then I would continue cloning the 'sections' property of this document. But for each 'section' document we also have other embedded documents and so on.

Is there any solution to this problem? I am concerned that in NoSQL databases it isn't a good idea having a tree model structure and collections being in relationships with others, would make it worse querying and also storing data. Also I know about embedding the whole document and not only the Id of the documents it refers to, but there is a limit for the document size in MongoDb which is 16mb and this is not something I strive for.

*Thank you for reaching this far and I hope you have understood the problem description. I also apologize for my bad english.*

----Edited
So after the cloning of a document, that is in the page collection, the database should look like:

**1. page collection**

```
{ 
"_id" : 4567890, 
"page_title" : "Title 1",
"sections" : [444, 555, ...]
"variables" : [v3, v4, ...]
}
```

**2. sections collection (note how this document can reference to other documents of the same collection)**

```
{ 
"_id" : 444, 
"section_tag" : "Section 1",
"sections" : [666, ...]
"blocks" : [3434, 4545, ...]
}
```

**3. blocks**

```
{ 
"_id" : 3434, 
"block_type" : "paragraph" (or image etc.),
"content" : "<p> content goes here...</p>"
"conditions" : [condition_id_3, condition_id_4, ...] (these are also embedded documents ID's)
}
```

Comment: You can use JsonConvert to serialize and deserialize to create a copy of an object with other child objects.

Comment: @Jawad I am sorry but how is serializing and deserializing related with deep cloning a document in mongodb? I am not working with json.

Comment: All mongodb documents are json documents. You can serialize and deserialize the objects in C# normally to create a "deep clone".

Comment: @floralb there is a DeepClone method for the BsonDocument class. Have tried to check that ? https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_BsonDocument_DeepClone.htm

Comment: @floralb this is the source code for the method: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/cf62d156f72a517c4bb61046ddb23104f58ece0c/src/MongoDB.Bson/ObjectModel/BsonDocument.cs#L821

Comment: Yes @EnricoMassone I have checked that method but it doesn't do the cloning based on different collections, it will only copy the Bson elements as they are, so for example the property named 'sections' on the 'page' document will be copied as an array with the same values of document ids.

Comment: couple of questions. 1.) when you mean embedded, have you only embedded the Id of the other document? if so, this is called a reference, not an embed. 2.) when you mean clone, do you want to make a copy of a page in the database (in a separate collection) which also has the sections and blocks fully populated? or are you talking about `retrieving` a page with all child/referenced docs populated? or do you already have that retrieved and just want to make a deep clone in c# of a page instance?

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ Hello thank you for correcting me, yes I meant the Id of another document in another collection.
2. I want to make a copy of a page in the same collection not in a separate collection.
The referenced documents should also be cloned. I will edit my post and show how the database should look like.

Comment: i'm afraid there's no easy way to do what you want other than to retrieve everything (including nested stuff) and save them one by one after setting new id values. you can use the extension method i posted below to clone the objects in your c# code.

Answer (score 0):

if you're talking about deep cloning a c# poco, you can use the following extension method for that:

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T Duplicate<T>(this T source)
    {
        return BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Container<T>>(
            new Container<T> { Data = source }.ToBson()
            ).Data;
    }

    private class Container<T>
    {
        public T Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and you can use it like so:

```cs
Page copy = page.Duplicate();
```

you will need the following imports:

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
```